# Выборка ячейки таблицы

Tags: jquery, javascript, выборка

Есть такая таблица:

```
<tr class='8768'><td>COL 1</td><td>COL 2</td><td>COL 3</td></tr>
<tr class='9809'><td>COL 1</td><td>COL 2</td><td>COL 3</td></tr>
<tr class='9515'><td>COL 1</td><td>COL 2</td><td>COL 3</td></tr>
...
<tr class='6969'><td>COL 1</td><td>COL 2</td><td>COL 3</td></tr>
```

К примеру нужно сделать выборку ячейки, у которой `class='9515'` и колонка №3. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на jquery, наверное будет выглядеть так:

```
$(".9515> td").each(function(index,Element){if (index==2){cell=$(Element).html();}});
```

Где Element и будет та ячейка, а html() - вернет ее содержимое.

Либо еще вот так:

```
$(".9515").children("td").each(function(index,Element){if (index==2){cell=$(Element).html();}});
```

И последний вариант, самый лучший спасибо [[@aachurin](/users/5267/aachurin)](/users/5267/aachurin)

```
$(".9515 > td").eq(2).html()
```

Comment: @culebre, у вас получился результат? У меня выдало "object object".

Comment: На каком варианте?

Comment: В 1) и 2). В 3) он вывел мне `<td>COL 1</td><td>COL 2</td><td>COL 3</td></tr>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/culebre/HG7sm - рабочий вариант

Comment: P.S. А что за сайт был?

Comment: В смысле? jsfiddle? Js редактор на облаке, ничего особенного, но очень удобная штука. По крайней мере для js. Хотя, что-то я видел подобное для пхп но не впечатлило.

Comment: Подправил первый вариант тоже работает.

Answer (score 2):

$("tr .9515").children('td').eq(2)

Comment: @aachurin, мне вывело пустое поле.

Comment: Странно, почему не работает, ведь по логике должно

Comment: там лишний пробел между tr и .9515, когда копировал не заметил. Должно быть $('tr.9515').children('td').eq(2)

Comment: Ну да, правда children можно заменить >td, я думаю накладные расходы будут меньше

Comment: вряд ли, там же парсер запросов используется

Comment: чем проще и точнее запрос тем лучше